# How to enable org-mode to search attachment in parent header's attachment folder

Tags: org-mode

I have an org file that has content like below:

```
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       6dc9fdfe-d24a-4eaf-8152-1f663ba70a2e
:END:
#+title: example
* Header
[[attachment:filename]]
```

Here the file `filename` is in the folder that is named based on the ID value: `.attach/6d/c9fdfe-d24a-4eaf-8152-1f663ba70a2e`, and I can link to the file without any issue.

After I run `org-id-get-create` for `* Header`, I had a new ID added for the header, and it becomes something like below

```
* Header
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       cd858afc-45ca-4f3d-bde8-a6f68c8acad0
:END:
[[attachment:filename]]
```

Now the attachment link to the file `filename` does not work any more, I have to move the file to a new folder for the new ID created, i.e., `.attach/cd/858afc-45ca-4f3d-bde8-a6f68c8acad0`.

This is annoying and I just wonder if there is a way to let the header `* Header` to search attachment in its parent's attachment folder as well? I tried to set `org-attach-use-inheritance` or set `org-use-property-inheritance` to `t`, but neither works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation (`C-h i g(org)attachment options`) says:

> Inheritance works the same way for both ‘ID’ and ‘DIR’ property. If both properties are defined on the same headline then ‘DIR’
> takes precedence.  This is also true if inheritance is enabled.  If ‘DIR’ is inherited from a parent node in the outline, that property still takes precedence over an ‘ID’ property defined on the node itself.

So in addition to the `ID`, try adding a `DIR` property with the parent's `ID` as value. Perhaps better, try making the parent's `ID` property a `DIR` property instead. If I read the doc right, that should allow you to add an `ID` property to the child and *still* have the attachment link work.

Untested.

Comment: The issue i have is that i am using org-roam, for which i always use `org-id-get-create` to make a header a roam node.

Using :DIR: would work, but i have to manually add that to PROPERTY everytime i run `org-id-get-create`, in order to make sure any subheader will work by inheriting the folder from its parent...

Comment: IIUC, you only have to do that once per file: create it as a file property: `#+PROPERTY: DIR foo`.